# Ios Location Permission is displayed even before App is launched and disappears Also didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called in this Scenario

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, appdelegate, xcode7.3

When i delete the app from Iphone and Run my project again The app is installed and Location Permission is asked even before the app is launched after that it disappears too quickly before user can interact with it. In this scenario the breakpoints in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and main.m is not working at all but the app is Loading the first screen And Notification permission is Loading .I cannot forward the app to signup screen since the app requires Location for finding the nearest counties users can register But when I stop the project and run again everything is working as it should be I cannot find the reason for this problem How is the app asking for permission without even entering didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? And proceeding to first page in storyboard without even entering viewdidLoad of that particular class

Comment: Please upload the code for your didFinishLaunching

Comment: Where have you initialised the CLLocation Manager instance & implemented the code for permissions ?? reply ASAP.

Comment: CLLocation Manager in appdelegate.h Initialization &permissions in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions   appdelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

If you once allow or granted the permission then it will not ask second time. So your flow is normal. Location service asks for permission with high priority so it will shown little bit earlier. If you want this on sign up screen then you should implement that code in your `viewDidload` of signup screen.

**Update :** (In response to comment)

If you uninstall or delete app from device or simulator that means you are deleting it's all data and configuration or settings(include your location permission). So, if you install it again then there is no permissions set in your device's setting app for your app. So, you got asked again for permission. that's it.

Comment: The issue happens when I Delete the app from iphone  and run again So if its reinstalled while running the project it should be asking for permission Right?

Comment: Check my update in answer. It was little long so i have updated answer instead to reply in comment!!1

Comment: Yeah The permission is asked again it is correctly working but the problem is its asked even before the app is launched and The Main issue is didFinishLaunching and main.m is not called in this scenario

Comment: Why are you not putting your code for permission in viewdidload as i have suggest earlier ?

Comment: I have to update location in various scenarios so I do that by calling the function in appdelegate for updating location so  it was easy for me to post a notification to sign up page  while didUpdateToLocation was called

Comment: then what is the problem if app asks one time for permission? Because it will be like that if you will called this from `didfinishlaunching...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120084/discussion-between-user3354805-and-ketan-parmar).